# WebSocket почему-то выдает ошибку 200 что не так делаю?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Что не так делаю ? Выдает ошибку WebSocket connection to 'ws://gtiradio.ru/count2.php' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

```
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://gtiradio.ru/count2.php");
        socket.onopen = function() {
          alert("Соединение установлено.");
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
          if (event.wasClean) {
            alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
          } else {
            alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
          }
          alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
          alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
        };

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
          alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
        };
```

Comment: Сокет (вебсокет, винсокет и т.п.) характеризуется адресом и портом. Т.е. если есть вебсокет-сервер, то он слушает какой-то порт (ждет подключения на этот порт). И у клиента при подключении к серверу указывается порт. Т.е. запись строки подключения имеет вид, например "ws://site.ru:15000". А по Вашему вопросу и коду можно предположить, что у Вас банально нет вебсокет-сервера и понятия об этой технологии Вы не имеете.

Comment: @MaxZS, порт клиенту указывать необязательно. Если не указать - на дефолтный пробросит. Так что код адекватный, за исключением того, что в обработчики придет немного не то что ожидает автор.

Comment: @ru_volt Необязательно? Да? И какой же будет дефолтный?

Comment: @MaxZS, 80 для ws, 443 для wss

Comment: @MaxZS, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7118, секция 5.5 в конце

Comment: @ru_volt Отлично! Так и что за сервер будет на 80-м порту у него?
Так что игнорить параметры или не писать их - это ошибка, а никак не адекватный код.

Comment: @MaxZS, какой он напишет, такой и будет. Клиентский код в части отправки запроса - верный. Он верно отрабатывает. Отрабатывает одинаково и предсказуемо, во всех клиентах, реализующих стандарт. То что лучше писать порт, не спорю. Но это не ошибка а вопрос стиля.

Comment: @ru_volt 80-й порт зарезервирован под http-протокол и на нем будет в охренительно подавляющем большинстве висеть http-вебсервер, обрабатывающий этот самый протокол. Так что не писать порт в данном случае - это ошибка, возникшая из-за непонимания вообще технологии вебсокетов.

Comment: @MaxZS, я действительно понятия не имею о этой технологии и только пробую. Но делаю все по учебнику https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets

Comment: @Max ZS, корону сними! Я пробовал с портом та же история

Comment: Вроде никогда короны и не носил. О том, что Вы не понимаете, что делаете в принципе, вообще без стеснения нужно было написать в вопросе. И даже не понимаете, что я писал в целом - никакой порт Вам не поможет - у Вас банально нет websocket сервера. Порт прописывается тот, который слушается сервером. ru_volt по факту только дальше Вас от решения задачи увел своим ответом и разглагольстваванием. В целом я рад Вашем агрессивному настрою. Но его не против меня, а на решение вопроса направить бы. А так... Раз у меня корона, а такие помощники Вам не нужны, то и я, в помощи Вам, так сказать, "пас".

Comment: @Max ZS, Ваша "помощь" не нужна, вопрос решился!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Ошибка на сервере.** Клиент запрашивает вебсокеты верно, а вот судя по ответу от вашего сервера, он сейчас вообще не понимает, что к нему обращаются за вебсокетами, поэтому хендшейк и не осуществляется.

В нормальном случае (сервер умеет вебсокеты) заголовки ответа выглядят как-то так:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
```

(`sec-websocket-accept` конечно будет выглядеть как-то по-другому)

Если Вы еще не настраивали какую-либо реализацию вебсокетов на сервере, сделайте это. Иначе покажите серверный код отдельным вопросом.

**Что такое хендшейк?**
Вебсокет это отдельный протокол. Реализованный далеко не везде (в отличие от дефолтного http). Поэтому клиенту чтобы общаться по вебсокетам, надо понимать что сервер их умеет. И хендшейк - процедура в которой клиент и сервер договариваются что они умеют вебсокеты (притом одну и ту же версию, стандарт еще достаточно молодой). То есть в самом простом случае происходит примерно следующее:

**Вариант 1:**
*Клиент (по http):* Эй, чувак, ты умеешь вебсокеты?  Если да, давай дальше через них.
*Сервер:* ага, давай дальше по-вебсокетному.

**Вариант 2:**
*Клиент (по http):* Эй, чувак, ты умеешь вебсокеты?  Если да, давай дальше через них.
*Сервер:* ммм.. чо? Верну-ка я "ок" (код 200).
*Клиент - юзеру:* Он ничего не понимает

На практике все совсем чуть-чуть сложнее, еще при хендшейке добавляется маска sec-websocket-accept для защиты от [отравления кеша](http://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88).